# Can any one explain the Non GUI Mode command for Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am running the `Jmeter jxm` project using the command prompt with the following command..

```
Jmeter -n -t filename.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Can any one explain this command?

Comment: Have to tried to figure it out by looking at the documentation first?
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into [How do I run JMeter in non-gui mode?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) guide

- `-n` - switch to run in non-GUI mode
- `-t` - location of .jmx source script
- `-l` - location of results file

Complete help entry:

```
    -h, --help
            print usage information and exit
    -v, --version
            print the version information and exit
    -p, --propfile <argument>
            the jmeter property file to use
    -q, --addprop <argument>
            additional JMeter property file(s)
    -t, --testfile <argument>
            the jmeter test(.jmx) file to run
    -l, --logfile <argument>
            the file to log samples to
    -j, --jmeterlogfile <argument>
            jmeter run log file (jmeter.log)
    -n, --nongui
            run JMeter in nongui mode
    -s, --server
            run the JMeter server
    -H, --proxyHost <argument>
            Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
    -P, --proxyPort <argument>
            Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
    -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
            Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
    -u, --username <argument>
            Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
    -a, --password <argument>
            Set password for proxy server that JMeter is to use
    -J, --jmeterproperty <argument>=<value>
            Define additional JMeter properties
    -G, --globalproperty <argument>=<value>
            Define Global properties (sent to servers)
            e.g. -Gport=123
             or -Gglobal.properties
    -D, --systemproperty <argument>=<value>
            Define additional system properties
    -S, --systemPropertyFile <argument>
            additional system property file(s)
    -L, --loglevel <argument>=<value>
            [category=]level e.g. jorphan=INFO or jmeter.util=DEBUG
    -r, --runremote
            Start remote servers (as defined in remote_hosts)
    -R, --remotestart <argument>
            Start these remote servers (overrides remote_hosts)
    -d, --homedir <argument>
            the jmeter home directory to use
    -X, --remoteexit
            Exit the remote servers at end of test (non-GUI)
```

Comment: `[category=]level e.g. jorphan=INFO or jmeter.util=DEBUG` --- can you explain what `jorphan` and `jmeter.util` mean?